# Spring : Google drive not opening window on live server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, google-drive-api, authorization

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am working on Google drive integration. We tested everything on localhost, and it works fine. But now when we uploaded the code on server and we are trying to authenticate, the browser URL wont be automatically opened like it was opened in localhost for user to give permissions. What am I doing wrong. Here is my authentication code :

Controller code :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/authorizeuser")
    public String testGoogleDrive(){
        try {
            this.driveQuickstart.authorize();
            return "redirect:/dashboard";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/denied";
        }
    }
```

DriveQuickStartImpl :

```
@Override
    public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        InputStream in =
                DriveQuickstartImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        if(credential!=null && credential.getRefreshToken() != null){
            storeCredentials(credential);
        }
        return credential;
    }
```

In tomcat console I see this :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=clientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39174/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

in client_secret.json, I changed the redirect_uri to mysite.de and even in developer console.

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"clientid","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_email":"","client_x509_cert_url":"","client_secret":"mysecret","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://mysite.de"]}}
```

Any help would be nice to know what the browser URL is not opening. Thanks a lot.